# How to use OSRM match api in leaflet to draw a route?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, osrm, map-matching, leaflet-routing-machine

I have some gps generated data during a drive.

```
var routeArr = [{lng1, lat1}, {lng2,lat2}, {lng3, lat3}.....];
```

I want to show this generated data as actual route traveled on a Leaflet powered Openstreet map.
My naive approach is to show a polyline connecting all points. But I want to show actual route which was followed while driving. 
Can I use [OSRM-Backend API](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/master/docs/http.md#service-match) with leaflet-routing-machine plugin for this?
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sadly there is not drop-in way to use this with LRM since the APIs work slightly differently.

1. The response contains `tracepoints` and `matchings` instead of `waypoints` and `routes`
2. An object in the `matchings` array is similar to a `Route` object but it represent sections of the gps trace that could be matched, not alternative routes like in the route plugin.

Easiest way to just deploy this on a map would be to run a query against:

`http://router.project-osrm.org/match/v1/driving/{lon,lat};{lon,lat};...?overview=full`

And then use https://github.com/mapbox/polyline and the following snippet to add the geometry on a map:

```
var polyline = require('polyline');

/* fetch the URL and save JSON in response */

response.matchings.map((m) => L.polyline(polyline.decode(m.geometry)).addTo(map));
```

Comment: This sounds really interesting! Can anyone provide an example code?